# Removing DIV With Button Within A DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following Code that adds a new TextBox and two new "buttons" to the TextBoxContainer div.

```
<div id="TextBoxContainer" style="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb"></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb" onclick="AddTextBox()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following code is executed on AddTextBox event:

```
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return  '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb1 Tb2"></textarea>' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="Tb1" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"></span>' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb2"  onclick="AddTextBox()"></span>' +
    '</div>'
}
```

Which creates this HTML code:

```
<div id="TextBoxContainer" style="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb"></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb" onclick="AddTextBox()"></span>
    </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb1 Tb2">
            </textarea><span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="Tb1" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"></span>
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb2" onclick="AddTextBox()"></span></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

**How do I modify RemoveTextBox(this) on click event function:**

```
function RemoveTextBox(div) {
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
```

In order to clear(remove) the newly added DIV - textbox and buttons?

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle for this, for everyone who wants to help to solve this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ohtjyz3e/

Comment: `Javascript` or `jquery` solution?

Comment: Javascript. I'm mostly doing back end ASP.Net coding, so I don't have a lot of JS experience, I was modifying the source code for JS I found online. The code works if you remove input-group div , however I need it in order to neatly display buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/94ppfrz6/)**

The problem with your `remove` function was you were trying to `removeChild` of `TextBoxContainer` by getting `parentNode` of `deleteButton`. The `parentNode` of delete button was not direct child of `TextBoxContainer` and hence it used to throw below error which is self-explanatory.

> **Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The
>   node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

So below approach where you create a new `div` with `document.createElement`, add a `class` - `input-group` to that particular `div` using `setAttribute` and then it would be direct child of `TextBoxContainer`

```
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.setAttribute('class',"input-group");
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
      return  '<textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb1 Tb2"></textarea>' +
      '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="Tb1" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"></span>' +
      '<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb2"  onclick="AddTextBox()"></span>' +
      '</div>'
}

function RemoveTextBox(div) {
     document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `div.parentNode.remove();` to remove that node.

```js
function AddTextBox() {
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
return  '<div class="input-group">' +
'<textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb1 Tb2"></textarea>' +
'<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="Tb1" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)">RemoveTextBox</span>' +
'<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb2"  onclick="AddTextBox()">AddTextBox</span>' +
'</div>'
}

function RemoveTextBox(div) {
div.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="TextBoxContainer" style="">
<div class="input-group">
<textarea rows="2" name="DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value="" aria-describedby="Tb"></textarea>
<span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="Tb" onclick="AddTextBox()">AddTextBox</span>
</div>
</div>
```